# FPGA soft IP cores : are they in general always chip dependent or independent

Tags: fpga

There are soft, hardened, and hard IP cores for FPGA. The hard IP cores/blocks are on the chip, and hardened may be a combination of soft and may referencing hard IP clocks. (from textbook)

But if we only consider the soft IP cores : are they in general independent of a specific FPGA chip, model, manufacturer?

Let's say it's delivered in an HDL and some set of configurations for various synthesis/implementation translation tools. Not say only fixed to Xilinx, or Intel. Is that HDL high enough for the IP to be synthesize on different manufacturer's FPGA chips, and architectures (or different fabrics)? Will the Soft IP be high enough?

I sort of, tend to think Yes, but I don't have good knowledge on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that most likely they'll only work on the platforms they were designed for without significant modifications. Many of the cores you use will come from the chip vendor, and those will invariably be tied to their platform one way or another. And even for cores from a third party, there's a good chance they'll be using primitives that are specific to certain chips or aren't optimized for or tested on other chips. Some cores are also encrypted, which locks you into certain toolchains and prevents you from modifying it yourself.

Having said that, it is possible to write portable HDL and there are cores like that out there. It's going to be more common for simpler cores that don't need to be heavily optimized with chip-specific techniques. But in general you shouldn't count on that being the case. If there's a core you want to use in a project, you should verify beforehand that it's designed for your chip family or be prepared to take on the effort to port and debug it yourself.

Comment: thank you for the answer, it is great. It seems to me, bottles down to the issue that targeting specific hardware/chip is required for performance is required for good IP.  So, the high or higher level that an HDL is , is still not quite same high level as a portable source code.